# How to avoid repeating the following replace code?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is the input:

```
[ 'markdown',
  [ 'para', '"a paragraph"' ],
  [ 'hr' ],
  [ 'para', '\'another paragraph\'' ],
  [ 'bulletlist', [ 'listitem', '"a list item"' ] ] ]
```

The following code loops through each element of the array. If the elements is another array the code goes one depth further and applies `replace`, if not, it applies `replace` immediately (if I didn't have that if statement `replace` on an array would cause error.

```
  for (i = 1; i < tree.length; i++) {
    var node = tree[i]
    var x = node.length - 1
    var y = node[x].length - 1

    if (Array.isArray(node[x])) {
      node[x] = node[x][y].replace(/"(?=\b)/g, '“')
                          .replace(/"(?!\b)/g, "”")
    } else {
      node[x] = node[x].replace(/"(?=\b)/g, '“')
                       .replace(/"(?!\b)/g, "”")
    }
  }
```

What bothers me is the duplication with `replace`. How can I modify the code so I just do `.replace(/"(?=\b)/g, '“').replace(/"(?!\b)/g, "”")` once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use iteration, valid for N-dimensional array

```
function doWork(tree){
  for (i = 1; i < tree.length; i++) {
    var node = tree[i]
    var x = node.length - 1
    var y = node[x].length - 1

    if (Array.isArray(node[x])) {
      doWork(node[x]);
    } else {
      node[x] = node[x].replace(/"(?=\b)/g, '“')
                       .replace(/"(?!\b)/g, "”")
    }
  }
}

// use it
doWork(tree);
```

Comment: Yep although the solution of @Sphaso is nice, I like a **`recursive`** one better, this will work till infinity.

Answer (score 2):

Extract logic in a function:

```
   function replaceMe(element) {
        return element.replace(/"(?=\b)/g, '“')
                      .replace(/"(?!\b)/g, "”");
    }


...
  for (i = 1; i < tree.length; i++) {
    var node = tree[i]
    var x = node.length - 1
    var y = node[x].length - 1

    if (Array.isArray(node[x])) {
      node[x] = replaceMe(node[x][y]);
    } else {
      node[x] = replaceMe(node[x]);
    }
  }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes two simple regex it's faster than one complex.

But you can try a different approach like this:

```
var example_string = '"some_string"',
    regex = /"(.*?)"/g;

var result = example_string.replace(regex, "“$1”");

console.log(result); // “some_string”
```

```